# Why does a Site Collection Appear in Graph/Sites and Not In Search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, microsoft-graph

I am progressively transitioning projects from classic Search API to the Microsoft Graph and encountering a few challenges. For example I currently use the following to get all Site Collections:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27path:https://tenant.sharepoint.com%27&selectProperties=%27Path,Title,SiteName,ContentClass%27&refinementFilters=%27ContentClass:equals(%22STS_SITE%22)%27&trimDuplicates=false
```

I am seeking to replace it with a graph query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

I have discovered that in one case, on one tenant, that a Site Collection appears in Graph, but not in Search. I have tried to replicate it by turning off **Indexing Site Content** but that hides the site from both. I cannot determine how this could be happening.

The other challenge I have is the Graph returns SPWebs and there is not an option to filter on SPSites. It appears that once I get my graph results I have to enumerate the results myself and find the webs that have  a `siteCollection` facet. Does anyone have a better solution? Is there a filter that simplifies this?